# Passing PHP variable value to jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, function

I'm new to Jquery. I have a project that has checkboxes and if their status change, then I update some sql table.

But i decided to start with the simple things first to learn how this works...

So, I want to pass to a Jquery function, a php variable if a checkbox status changes.

I have this code:

```
<?php ?>

<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
  <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function my_function(var mensagem_id)
        {
            alert("Sucesso, Mensagem nº: " + mensagem_id);
        }
    </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
 <?php 
    $mensagem_id = "3";
    echo $mensagem_id; 
 ?>
  <input type='checkbox' name='lida' value='mensagem_id' onchange='my_function($mensagem_id)'/>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

But in firebug I keep getting the message (function my_function() not defined)...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi guys,

I solved the issue by replacing "onchange" for "onclick". 
Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery runs on the client, whereas PHP runs on the server. So, there is no way to pass a PHP variable to a jQuery function. You could write directly to the onchange callback:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='lida' value='mensagem_id' onchange='my_function( <?php 
    $mensagem_id = "3";
    echo $mensagem_id; 
 ?>
)'/>
```

Also note that in jQuery you should avoid setting events this way and use jQuery events instead:

```
$('#myinputid').change(function() {
});
```

Another way will be to set a hidden field with the PHP variable and use javascript/jQuery code to read it on client side.

Comment: and can I pass variable values to that jquery event?

Comment: Yes, by using the same techniques

Answer (score 1):

Take "var" away from the function definition, and use `<?php echo` and `?>` around `$mensagem_id` in the `onchange` call.

But you're not using jQuery at all, just simple Javascript.

Comment: I know, it's only javascript for now, but later i want to add some jquery stuff but i need to start from here :)
I updated the code with your suggestion:
<?php ?>
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function my_function(mensagem_id)
  {
   alert("Sucesso, Mensagem nº: " + mensagem_id);
  }
 </script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <?php 
 $mensagem_id = "3";
 echo $mensagem_id; 
 ?>
  <input type='checkbox' name='lida' value='mensagem_id' onchange='my_function(<?php echo $mensagem_id; ?>)'/>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't have to use that `var` in your function parameter...

Comment: Very true. Parameters are not the places to declare variables. It should just be (mensagem_id). Or, better, (mId) or something short--you don't need to declare it, just pass it when you call the function.

Comment: I tried that but still get the my_function() not defined, message :(