# passing varibles into j-query from php as attributes

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to pass the attribute `location` into jquery but unable to do so 
could some one point out on what m i doing wrong

**php**

```
   <?php echo "<a class='classloader'   location='$array[$i]' href='#'>$array[$i]</a>";  ?>
```

**Jquery**

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var location= $(this).attr('location');
         $(".classloader").click(
             function () {
                 display();
             }
         );
     });

 function display() {
  $('#contenthere').html(location);
 }

</script>
```

Comment: var location= $('a.classloader').eq(0).attr('location');

Comment: then Ctrl+U in browser and check for correct generated html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing PHP Variable Into jQuery Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284180/passing-php-variable-into-jquery-function)

Comment: I wondering is there have many `class=classloader` in your html? Moreover, the `var location = $(this).attr('location');` referring to `<document>` but not that `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$(this)` outside the `click` handler, so it doesn't refer to the element that they clicked on.

Then you should pass the string as an argument to `display()`.

```
$(".classloader").click(function() {
    var location = $(this).attr("location");
    display(location);
});

function display(str) {
    $('#contenthere').html(str);
}
```

BTW, you shouldn't make up your own attributes like that, they might conflict with future HTML versions. Use `data-XXX` attributes, which are reserved for programmers.

```
<?php echo "<a class='classloader' data-location='$array[$i]' href='#'>$array[$i]</a>";  ?>
```

Then in jQuery you can use `$(this).data('location')` to access it.

Comment: for some reason the `data-XXX` doesnt work
but it works when i give my own attr

Comment: There's no reason why `data-location` shouldn't work, you must have made a mistake.

Comment: Access it with either `.attr('data-location')` or `.data('location')`.